# Optimum solution for searching similar rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to this macro world. Started working on it from yday.
i created a macro.
the excel workbook has two sheets. sheet1 and sheet2

**Sheet1:**

```
A   B   C  D  E
1   2   3  4  3
5   6   7  8  2
9   10  11 12 1
11  12  14 14 3
```

**Sheet2:**

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  2  3  4  7
13 14 17 20 2
5  6  7  8  1
```

so when the rows in sheet2 (1st 4 A,B,C,D) matches with the rows in sheet1 the values in E should get multiplied and stored in another sheet.
for example,
sheet2 , 1 2 3 4 matches with 1 2 3 4 in sheet1, so the number in E (7 and 3) should get multiplied and the result should be stored in sheet3.

below is the snippet i developed.

```
Sub test()

Dim sh1 As Range
Set sh1 = Sheet1.UsedRange

Dim sh2 As Range
Set sh2 = Sheet2.UsedRange

Dim sh3 As Range
Set sh3 = Sheet3.UsedRange

For i = 1 To sh1.Rows.Count

    For m = 1 To sh2.Rows.Count

     Match = True

        For j = 1 To sh1.Columns.Count

            If (sh1.Cells(i, j).Value <> sh2.Cells(m, j).Value) Then Match = False

            If (Match = False) Then Exit For

        Next j

     If Match = True Then sh1.Cells(i, 4).Value = _
                sh1.Cells(i, 4).Value * sh2.Cells(m, 4).Value

    Next m
Next i

End Sub
```

this worked fine. but this is kind of a linear search, so when loads of data is given, the excel gets hung up.
Is there a more **optimum solution**? Maybe like binary search or search by sort.

Comment: So there will always be 4 cells matched and then for the last one column the values are to be multiplied? Right now your code checks all values for a match, so it's not clear how it could work as written.

Comment: You could use arrays

Comment: it'd probably be quicker to concatenate the 4 values together in a helper column and then use something like Match to see if that concatenated value exists in the other sheet.  That should get rid of a few of the loops you've got in your code, which will make it considerably faster.

Comment: Similar? It sounds like you want to get exact match...

Answer (score 0):

This worked pretty quickly for me on your test data.  I made some assumptions on your sheet references as well as being able to use some helper columns.  You can also use a more reliable way to get the last row used, but this should at least get you close:

```
Sub Test()
Dim lrSheet1    As Long, _
    lrSheet2    As Long, _
    counter     As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

With Sheet2
    lrSheet2 = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    .Range("F1:F" & lrSheet2).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1)"
End With

With Sheet1
    lrSheet1 = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    .Range("F1:F" & lrSheet1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1)"
    .Range("G1:G" & lrSheet1).Formula = "=Match(F1,Sheet2!F:F,0)"
End With


With Sheet3
    For counter = 1 To lrSheet1
        If IsNumeric(Sheet1.Range("G" & counter)) Then _
            Sheet3.Range("A" & counter).Value = Sheet1.Range("E" & counter).Value * Sheet2.Range("E" & Sheet1.Range("G" & counter)).Value
    Next counter
End With

Sheet1.Range("F1:G" & lrSheet1).Delete
Sheet2.Range("F1:F" & lrSheet2).Delete

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Basically it uses 2 formulas.  the first concatenates the values together.  The match formula returns the row reference for a match on Sheet2.  Once you have that, it's just a matter of looping through the values on Sheet1 and if there is a numeric (meaning there is a match) you multiply the value on Sheet1 column 5 with the matching value (row number) of Sheet2 column 5.

On limitation of my approach is if you have multiple matches on Sheet2 (meaning 1234 exists more than once). Not sure if that's a possibility or not.  If it is, it would require a slightly different approach...